# Need the right term about a roll of toilet paper

Tags: word-request, terminology

Help is needed for obtaining the right term in the following description (in quote):-

A roll of toilet paper is in the form of continued sheets. These sheets are connected (or separated) by “pre-cut/pre-punched/pre-slotted dotted cutting lines”.

Comment: Perforated. Search of Facebook for "quilted northern rustic weave video", which was published on April 1st. Note... April 1st.

Comment: You should probably use **continuous** rather than **continued**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term that is usually used is *perforated*, e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_paper):

> It is sold as a long strip of perforated paper [...]

*Perforated* describes exactly the (many) holes / slits / cuts that separate the individual sheets.

Answer (score 0):

To sound more like a native English speaker, I would update your sentences to the following:

> A roll of toilet paper is in the form of continuous sheets. These sheets are perforated, making them easy to separate.

Comment: "To **sound** like a native english speaker?"  This might be what a native english speaker would write, but I can't imagine anybody talking like that.

Comment: @JavaLatte if this was my industry, this is how I would speak these sentences... as a native speaker.  The person sounded like they were speaking technically to explain or sell the product.